# Difference between $\Delta_g \phi$ and $\Delta \phi ~$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

Let $\phi$ be a smooth function on a Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$.

Now, we could write $\nabla_g \phi$ as

$$\nabla_g \phi = \sum^n_{i,j=1} g^{ij} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = g^{ij} \partial_i \phi ~ \partial_j  \tag{1}$$

and

$$\text{div}X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i \left({\sqrt{|g|} }X^i \right) \tag{2}$$

where $X^i \in T_p{M}$ in local coordinate.

Thus

$$\Delta_g \phi = \text{div} \nabla_g \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i \left({\sqrt{|g|} }g^{ij}\partial_j \phi \right) \tag{3}$$

We also have

$$\Delta \phi = \nabla^i \nabla_i \phi = g^{ij} \nabla_i \nabla_j \phi \tag{4}$$

**Questions:**

1. What is the difference between $\Delta_g \phi$ and $\Delta \phi ~$ ?
2. Could I rewrite (4) as

$$\Delta \phi = \nabla^i \nabla_i \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i \left({\sqrt{|g|} }g^{ij}\partial_j \phi \right)? \tag{5}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection, then they are the same (on scalar functions). This follows from the identity
$$\Gamma^i_{ij}=|g|^{-1/2}\partial_j|g|^{1/2}$$
for the contracted Christoffel symbols.
We therefore obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g^{ij}\nabla_i\nabla_j\phi&=g^{ij}\nabla_i\partial^j\phi \\
&=\nabla_i\partial^i\phi=\partial_i\partial^i\phi+\Gamma^i_{ij}\partial^j\phi \\
&=\partial_i\partial^i\phi+\big(|g|^{-1/2}\partial_i|g|^{1/2}\big)\partial^i\phi\\
&=|g|^{-1/2}\big(\partial_i\partial^i\phi\big) |g|^{1/2} +\big(|g|^{-1/2}\partial_i|g|^{1/2}\big)\partial^i\phi\\
&=|g|^{-1/2}\partial_i\big(|g|^{1/2} \partial^i\phi\big).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

They are the same as shown in S.Surace's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2836059/99914).

One can calculate at the center of a normal coordinates, at this center we have

$$ \Delta \phi = \Delta_g \phi  = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_i^2}$$